# Stock JB ROMs for Chinese-made devices

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, hardware, rom, stock-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I'm looking for a good source for MT, RK and Allwinner-based phones and tablets, but I couldn't find any. Most just target specific western models.